# Spring get bean without implementation

Tags: spring

I try do all things as here

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

But i get error, when try repeat this line

```
 ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
```

in my app this seems so

```
@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext;
```

error that i get when call getBean function

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [ru.tcsbank.target.core.service.TestRepository] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
```

What is the problem with this example?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace. and your code please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BhrB7DpE  - stacktrace:)

Comment: Please add it to your question not as a link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UrqFtkcu - code:)

Comment: i am sorry, it was test app context
now i have other problems
here is stacktrace http://pastebin.com/ydZBACDp

Comment: Can you copy Text to your question and not Link to other sides please.

Comment: i have too little reputation points for creating chat

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues that could be causing this. Code from the TestRepository object would be helpful.

From what you've provided, my best guess is that some object, likely the TestRepository, is being wired in, but is missing the annotation to tell Spring it's a bean. Check that the proper objects have `@Entity`, `@Service`, `@Component`, and `@Repository`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `@Repository` annotation to your `TestRepository`.

Comment: i try this, but this does not help

Comment: Can you add more code not only the snipped that is attached as link.

Comment: Have you activated component scan?